How can I reconnect AWS DMS after Blue Green deployment
We have an AWS RDS for PostgreSQL on 13.15 and AWS Redshift gets data from the instance using AWS DMS. To upgrade the 13.15 to 16, we are testing with Blue/Green approach. It is necessary to stop the DMS jobs and drop the logical replication slots to carry out a Blue/Green deployment. That part works fine. After switchover, I created a logical replication slot with the same name/type as the one I dropped, on the new RDS instance. But the DMS job fails with errors. In short, the question is - if we stop a DMS job, drop the replication slot, the RDS instance is upgraded, how can we make the DMS job take over from where it left off? The error is
SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host ""10.*.0.*"", user ""x"", database ""x"", no encryption [1022502]  (ar_odbc_conn.c:604)"

But I think that error message is misleading.

It was indeed a connectivity issue. The parameter rds.force_ssl was 0 in RDS 13.15 and the default value in Version 16 is 1. Changing it to 0 resolved the connectivity issue.
